# Scrape currency exchange data from https://uzmanpara.milliyet.com.tr/doviz-kurlari/

Tags: java, jsoup

I need get the currency data from website, here the website `HTML` table code:

```html
<tr>
   <td class="currency-up"></td>
   <td class="currency">
      <a href="/dolar-kuru/" target="_blank" data-adservice-interactive-adunit="9927946/milliyet/uzmanpara/interstitial_oop">ABD Doları</a>
   </td>
   <td class>8,2805</td>
   <td class>8,2856</td>
</tr>
```

I wrote these code but I could not handle the code:

```
String url = "https://uzmanpara.milliyet.com.tr/doviz-kurlari/";
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(6000).get();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(den3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
Element link = doc.select("href").first();

String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
System.out.println(linkHref);
```

But I got this problem:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke "org.jsoup.nodes.Element.attr(String)" because "link" is
> null

How can I handle this problem, how can I get currency rate.

Comment: You should clearly state what output you wanted to produce by using Jsoup to extract site data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```java
Element link = doc.select("a[href]").first();
```

If you just type `href`, it will search for the **`href` tagname**, but there is never such a tagname. You have to look for the `href` attribute of the `a` tag.

#### Let's start with a simple example.

Example, to get the value of the 2nd `span` below the element whose `href` value is `/dolar-kuru/`, you can try:

```java
// Example of selection with id.
Element element2 = doc.select("#usd_header_son_data").first();
String usd2 = element2.text();
System.out.println(usd2);

// Example of selecting 2nd span with href value and below. (1)
Element element1 = doc.select("a[href='/dolar-kuru/'] > span > span").first();
String usd1 = element1.text();
System.out.println(usd1);

// Example of selecting 2nd span with href value and below. (2)
Element element3 = doc.select("a[href='/dolar-kuru/'] > span :nth-child(2)").first();
String usd3 = element3.text();
System.out.println(usd3);
```

#### We can take the example one step further.

Let's take both the buy and sell prices from a table of exchange rates.

```java
Elements elements = doc.select(".borsaMain > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > table td.currency");
for (Element element : elements) {
    Elements curreny = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(2)");
    Elements buy = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(3)");
    Elements sell = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(4)");
    System.out.println(String.format("%s [buy=%s, sell=%s]",
            curreny.text(), buy.text(), sell.text()));
}
```

Will give an output that looks like this:

```
ABD Doları [buy=8,2855, sell=8,2888]
Euro [buy=9,8389, sell=9,8645]
İngiliz Sterlini [buy=11,4203, sell=11,4775]
Kanada Doları [buy=6,5696, sell=6,6091]
İsviçre Frangı [buy=9,0128, sell=9,0671]
Suudi Riyali [buy=2,2025, sell=2,2135]
...
```

More different selectors can be used, see. https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: I use this code but I got a long text, it returns all text of the website., how can I split it in array it does not work

Comment: Returns only the **`a` tag** with the first **`href` attribute** it finds.

Comment: thanks so much, it works, in Turkish "Allah Razı Olsun"...

Comment: Dear İsmail, yesterday this program was worked but after midnight, it did not work since now, I got NULL value, I change the Document connect via Document parse but still does not get any value, how can I handle it

Comment: I tried again now it works, If there is a connection problem, consider that they may be vulnerable when you want to retrieve data from a persistent source.

Answer (score 0):

For the provided HTML code, you can do the following:

```
Element link = doc.select("a[href]").first();
String linkHref = link.attr("href");
System.out.println(linkHref);
```

For the url provided in the code sample, if you want to select only the first, you can do:

```
Element link = doc.select("td.currency > a").first();
String linkHref = link.attr("href");
System.out.println(linkHref);
```

Just to explain the previous code: "td.currency" will search for "td" tags with the class "currency". And " > a" will retrieve the child elements which are a "a" tag.

And if you want all currencies you can do

```
Elements links = doc.select("td.currency > a");
links.forEach(link -> System.out.println(link.attr("href")));
```

Note that there are some duplicates in the last code sample.

Comment: I tried all the above answers there were useful but I could not get the data "8,28" in <td class>8,2805</td>